# Embedded For loops for a precipitation map, with Perlin noise in the Unity3d game engine issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a precipitation map for an experiment with Perlin noise, where I also create biomes.

I am using temperature and precipitation to determine a biome of a certain pixel, I have the program for the precipitation, but the multiple `For loops` in the program is making Unity3d become unresponsive for a long period of time.

Does anyone know how to make this faster? I have looked around on the internet, but I couldn't find an answer

Here is my code:

```
public float[,] PrecipMap (float[,] noise,int mapWidth,int mapHeight)
{
    float[,] precipMap = new float[mapWidth, mapHeight];//array that it to be used for precipitation
    float[,] waterTiles = WaterTiles(mapHeight, mapWidth, noise);//array with all values that are water
    for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
        {

        float[] distance = new float[count];//distance between pixel and water tile
        for(int wy = 0; wy < mapHeight; wy++)
        {
            for(int wx = 0; wx < mapWidth; wx++)
            {
                if (waterTiles[x, y] == 1) { // if the selected tile in water tiles has water
                    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)// distance makes an array of all possible distances. 
                        {
                            distance[i] = Mathf.Sqrt(((x + -wx) * (x + -wx)) + ((y +-wy) * (y +-wy)));// finds distance between pixel and water tile 
                        } 

                    }
                }
                Array.Sort(distance); /// sorts distance from least to greatest
                precipMap[x, y] = distance[count-1];//enters in distance

            }
        }
    }

    return precipMap;
}
```

If anyone could help, I would be thankful. I am very grateful for any help/criticism.

Comment: What's the size of your map? E.g. what values are being plugged into `mapWidth` and `mapHeight`?

Comment: Right now the width and height are both 75

Comment: Nested loops add up very quickly, especially when you go beyond a single nested loop. Just to put things into perspective, in this case to run your `PrecipMap` function one time you are asking your program to loop `75^3 * count` times which is likely somewhere in the millions, depending on the value of count - `421,875 * count`. Consider drastically reducing the size of your inputs and/or taking another approach that requires fewer nested loops.

Comment: You're recalculating and overwriting `precipMap[x,y]` for every `wy` iteration, and also sorting `distance` at the same time. This is unnecessary. Considering moving that up to the containing loop.

Comment: Don't allocate new arrays inside of a nested loop unless it is absolutely necessary. (In this case, it is not.) Garbage collection goes into overdrive and kills perf.

Comment: I have no idea where `count` is defined, but it's not clearly modified in your code as posted. You're repeatedly assigning the last value in `distance` to every element in `precipMap`. Just track the max `distance` value rather than stuffing it into an array that you're constantly reallocating. Sorting is expensive, as are allocations.

Comment: Thanks. The count integer is defined by the number of water squares. It is about 1.5 thousand.

Comment: it also depends how and where you run this code

Answer (score 0):

As was already commented your loops run quite often and by default everything in unity runs on the main thread. So before Unity can render the next frame, you method has to finish.

Additionally you run `Array.Sort` which is quite expensive and allocate new arrays for each iteration which also keeps your GC busy!

Then I don't see what your `distance` array is good for. The variable `i` is Neve used in yoir calculation so you just fill all 1500 entries with the same value, sort it and read out the last one ... They will all be equal anyway so this is completely redundant!

Also you check redundantly

```
if (waterTiles[x, y] == 1)
```

which would be enough to check **once** as soon as you have `x` and `y` and is unnecessarily done further below within the nested loops - loops that you could have skipped completely if the condition is false anyway.

You could actually move your entire method to a thread and wait for the result using [async await](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) (also see [Using async-await in Unity3D](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017)). Unfortunately I'm no `async-await` expert but this should do it

```
public async void CalculatePrecipMap(float[,] noise, int mapWidth, int mapHeight, Action<float[,]> callback)
{
    var result = await PrecipMap(noise, mapWidth, mapHeight);

    callback?.Invoke(result);
}

private async Task<float[,]> PrecipMap (float[,] noise,int mapWidth,int mapHeight)
{
    //array that it to be used for precipitation
    float[,] precipMap = new float[mapWidth, mapHeight];
    //array with all values that are water
    float[,] waterTiles = WaterTiles(mapHeight, mapWidth, noise);

    for (var y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
        {   
            // Skip as soon as possible
            // Completely unnecessary to run your loop at all if this is already false
            if (waterTiles[x, y] != 1) continue; 

            // if the selected tile in water tiles has water

            for(var wy = 0; wy < mapHeight; wy++)
            {
                for(var wx = 0; wx < mapWidth; wx++)
                {
                    // i is nowhere used in below calculation!
                    // I don't see any reason to use an distance array here at all !!!                      
                    precipMap[x, y] = Mathf.Sqrt(((x + -wx) * (x + -wx)) + ((y +-wy) * (y +-wy)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return precipMap;
}
```

You would then use it using a lambda expression like

```
CalculatePrecipMap(someNoise, someWidth, someHeight, result =>
{
    // Do something with the result
}
```

or using a method like

```
CalculatePrecipMap(someNoise, someWidth, someHeight, OnResultReady);

private void OnResultReady (float[,] result)
{
    // Do something with the result
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Woah I didn't know that Unity had to do that all in one frame. I also didn't know that I could have a method like that. Thank you.